# How can I do KMeans clustering in python for 8 columns in a data-frame of 14 columns?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to do clustering for the data-frame given to me. It has 14 columns. How to do clustering for 8 of those?

Below is the code that I found and followed.

Elbow method:

[image: Elbow_method]

Visualization

[image: Visualization]

```
# K-Means Clustering

# importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# importing tha customer Expenses Invoices dataset with pandas
dataset=pd.read_csv('Expense_Invoice.csv')
X=dataset.iloc[: , [3,2]].values

# Using the elbow method to find  the optimal number of clusters
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
  kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter= 300, n_init= 10, random_state= 0)
  kmeans.fit(X)
  wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11),wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters K')
plt.ylabel('Average Within-Cluster distance to Centroid (WCSS)')  
plt.show()

# Applying k-means to the mall dataset
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++', max_iter= 300, n_init= 10, random_state= 0)
y_kmeans=kmeans.fit_predict(X)

# Visualizing the clusters
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 0, 0], X[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'red', label='Careful(c1)')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 2, 0], X[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label='Standard(c2)')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 1, 0], X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'blue', label='Target(c3)')
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s = 250, c = 'yellow', 
            label='Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters of customer Invoices & Expenses')
plt.xlabel('Total Invoices ')
plt.ylabel('Total Expenses')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This works perfectly but this is only for two columns(variables), i want to have it for 8 column. But I could not understand how?

Comment: You haven't included the code. When you say you're not able to do so, what specifically is the problem you're having?

Comment: Please have a look at the attached pics.

Comment: Dear Rup, please have a look, here are the codes.

Comment: Beware that k-means is *very* sensitive to attribute scaling and skewed data. So using it on attributes such as "invoices" probably is not meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

With `X=dataset.iloc[: , [3,2]].values` you are specifically the 4th and 3rd column. 
KMeans performs the clustering on all columns you selected.

Therefore you need to change `X=dataset.iloc[: , [3,2]]` to your needs. Eg to use the first 8 columns of your dataset: `X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:8].values`.

Take a look at pandas documentation for more options how to select data in dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Keep in mind that you can't visualize your clusters in a 2D scatter plot as you have done before.

Comment: It worked well and I moved ahead. I used PCA method to visualize the data and even trying tSNE but could not understand which one I should use!

Comment: It helped but I couldn't visualize the data. What should I do?